# how to add new columns with region and iso(for mapping) in R?

Tags: r, tibble, country-codes

My current data contains a column of 126 countries named "Country" and some other columns. I am trying to create new columns called "Continent",the continent of the countries, and "Country Code", the iso mapping code for the countries. I am currently having problems with my code.

```
 military_dta <-read_csv("Military Spending_Raw.csv")

 glimpse(military_dta)

 military_dta1 <- military_dta %>% drop_na()

 install.packages("countrycode")

 library(countrycode)

 military_dta1$continent <- countrycode(sourcevar = military_dta1[,
 "Country"],
                             origin = "country.name",
                             destination = "continent")
```

this is the error I got:

> Error in countrycode(sourcevar = military_dta1[, "Country"], origin =
>   "country.name",  :    sourcevar must be a character or numeric vector.
>   This error often
>                arises when users pass a tibble (e.g., from dplyr) instead of a
>                column vector from a data.frame (i.e., my_tbl[, 2] vs. my_df[, 2]
>                                                 vs. my_tbl[[2]])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error says, you're passing a tibble instead of a column vector. Try this...

```r
military_dta1$continent <- countrycode(sourcevar = military_dta1$Country,
                             origin = "country.name",
                             destination = "continent")
```

or as the error message suggests...

```r
military_dta1$continent <- countrycode(sourcevar = military_dta1[["Country"]],
                             origin = "country.name",
                             destination = "continent")
```